# PHP array compare then delete that is not inside

Tags: php

I have 2 variables with array value there.

```
$val1 = "PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg";
$val2 = "PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg";
```

`$val1` means the master data.
`$val2` means the unchecked value data.

What I need to do now check and compare that 2 variables that is not inside anymore.

Example, as We can see on value of `$val2` is not including `PRD_41088.jpg` then go to the query to delete it.

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tb_product_image WHERE product_image = '$getTheValueNotIncuding'");
```

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: The question title is about arrays, but there isn't a single array in your code (only CSV strings). It is really hard to even understand what your question is, but if the words don't match the code, it is nearly impossible to figure out, where the problem is in.

Comment: here is not data in array.It cotain string data.

Comment: Simply put: [Explode()](http://php.net/explode) both CSV strings on the comma. Use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the values that aren't present in `$val2`. Loop through the result array and delete the values.

Comment: First explode thiae strings to get arra and then check the inarray element the you can delete the same

Comment: Please check :- <?php

$val1 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
$val2 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");

$result = array_diff($val1,$val2);
foreach($result as $val){
 if(!empty($val)) {
     $q = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tb_product_image WHERE product_image = '$val'");
      }
} 
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;
?>

Comment: @sunnybhadania why did you not just provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 # Try Code

<?php

    $val1 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
    $val2 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");

    $result = array_diff($val1,$val2);
    foreach($result as $val){
         if(!in_array($val, $val2 )) { 
               $q = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tb_product_image WHERE product_image = '$val'");
          }
    }   
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the difference between both values then try [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
`print_r(array_diff(explode(',' , $val1), explode(',' , $val2)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$val1 = "PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg";
$val2 = "PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg";
// Converting the 2 Strings into arrays by exploding them with Delimiter ","
$val1Array = explode(",", $val1);
$val2Array = explode(",", $val2);

foreach($val1Array as $value) {
    //Looping through $val1 to check if the current value is also in $val2
    if( !(in_array($value, $val2Array))) {
        // Enter your Code to delete it here. 
        echo $value ." has to be deleted";
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why this is downvoted, it answers the question, and explains the whole process to him, as he seems like a newbie.

Comment: Probably meta - sometimes you get a down-vote for answering a shoddy question.

Answer (score 0):

Split up your values into arrays

```
 $val1_arr = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
 $val2_arr = explode(",", "PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
```

Then we loop over the contents of $val1_arr to check if an element is not in $val2_arr. If the element is not present, we delete it.

```
 foreach($val1_arr as $element_to_check) {
      if(!in_array($element_to_check, $val2_arr )) {
           $q = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tb_product_image WHERE product_image = '$element_to_check'");
      }
 }
```

Edit: As Progrock pointed out, i forget the second parameter of the function so my code would not work. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: in_array accepts two arguments.  Did you try your code?

Comment: You have your foreach back to front.  Did you try your code?

Comment: On the chance, that i am repeating myself, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First make your string as an array through `explode`

```
$val1 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_41088.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
$val2 = explode(",","PRD_65582.jpg,PRD_58966.jpg");
```

Then use `array_diff()` to get the differences

`$result=array_diff($val1,$val2);`

Then implode the $result and pass it to your query

`$getTheValueNotIncuding = implode(",",$result);`

**Use Implode incase If difference returns more than one value so you will be in safe side**

Alternatively your query should use `IN` not `=` because you don't know how many different results you get

```
DELETE FROM tb_product_image WHERE product_image IN('$getTheValueNotIncuding')
```

Comment: What if there is no difference?

Comment: Use a check If array is empty or not ? @Progrock